# Linear regression with infinite slope

Tags: r

I know how to perform simple linear regression in R but how to perform the regression with infinite slope (see an example with same dataset from excel) with R1 on x-axis and LAI1 on the y-axis.

```
   R1 LAI1 
233.7 1.34 
411.3 4.42 
143.4 3.57 
136.7 3.27 
249.0 5.53 
 59.0 1.79 
186.0 4.32 
185.0 2.58
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you clarify what "*how to perform the regression with infinite slope*" means.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "infinite slope"? This is how you would do it in R:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~R1, ~LAI1,
  233.7,  1.34,
  411.3,  4.42,
  143.4,  3.57,
  136.7,  3.27,
    249,  5.53,
     59,  1.79,
    186,  4.32,
    185,  2.58
  )


model1 <- lm(LAI1 ~ R1, data = df)
summary(model1)

plot(df$R1, df$LAI1)
abline(model1)
```

[image]